# Conditional formating not working after save with openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-2.7, openpyxl

I've got a simple script that just renames a Excel sheet tab and then saves.
There is conditional formatting within the spread sheet that changes a cells colour if it's greater or equal to another cells value. However, open opening the newly saved .xlsx file this conditional formatting is "broken" as it no longer responds to the appropriate input.

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook

myPath = "C:\\temp"
myFile = "cf_simple_test_original.xlsx"
f =  os.path.join(myPath, myFile)
wb = load_workbook(filename = f) # xlxs only
ws = wb.worksheets[0]
# change the tabs
ws.title = "G_Stefani"

mynewFile = myFile.replace("original", "script_saved")
f =  os.path.join(myPath, mynewFile)

wb.save(f)
```

The script seems to break the .xlsx I'm currently working on. I've replicated the conditional formatting in a new file but this seems unaffected. I'm still try to isolate what part of the spread sheet/script is causing the problem.
Has anyone else had problems with openpyxl and conditional formatting?

Comment: If you suspect there is a problem with openpyxl then please submit a bug report with a sample file. https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues?status=new&status=open

Comment: I suspect the problem lies with openpyxl, in which case I'll submit a bug report. I wanted to know if other people had encountered something similar.

Comment: Without a file it's very difficult to say. Support for conditional formatting in openpyxl is very good.

Comment: The file in question belongs to the client, so I'm trying to edit down a version without any classified info on it that will show the bug in the same way.

Comment: Sure. If necessary you can send the file by PM to me so that it doesn't become public. What version of openpyxl are you using?